# Como agrego el punto decimal a números con cero a la izquierda en PHP

Tags: php

Quiero agregar un punto decimal a números con 0 a la izquierda de este modo

```
$number = (1 + 1);
$number = str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`$number` me devuelve:

> 002

Necesito convertirlo a `0.02` sea cual sea el número

Comment: Que tal si divides $number / 100?

Comment: ya te dio la respuesta @alanfcm

Comment: @alanfcm publica tu comentario como respuesta y podré borrar la mía tranquilo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres, simplemente divide tu variable entre 100 asi:

```
$number = $number / 100;
```